# Flutter development without Xcode for iPhone on a Mac

Tags: iphone, xcode, flutter, visual-studio-code

I am new to flutter development, Can I build a flutter app on my mac without downloading Xcode or android studio and use my iPhone to emulate the app?. As I don't have enough space on my mac to download xcode. For any clarification on the question write in the comments. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need Xcode. https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos

Answer (score 0):

without x code its not possible so you need to download xcode.